# RegExps: Match a word that starts with a character using negation

Tags: regex, bash, grep, regex-negation

Trying to learn regular expressions.

After reading [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) section on http://regular-expressions.info about laziness, greediness, and negated character classes as an alternative to laziness, I tried to use it on my own, but I can't figure out why the following wouldn't work.

```
echo "hello world is this the way?" | grep -oE '\<w[^\>]+\>'
```

Expected output:

```
world
way
```

Actual output:

```
world is this the way
```

Do word boundary characters (`\< \>`) need special escaping inside character classes?

I'm just doing this on the cli (bash 4.2.45, osx mavericks) for testing purposes. Would that be a factor?

I know that `\b` is also a word boundary character, but if I use it so the regexp is like so: `\bw[^\b]+\b`, I get the same output, but it includes the question mark.

Thanks!

Update:

I'm looking for an answer that uses a negated character class, in order to avoid backtracking in the regex engine as explained [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) under **An Alternative to Laziness**. If it's not possible to use a negated character class, I'm looking for explanation as to why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
\bw\w+\b
```

This will capture all the words starting with `w` and consisting of word characters.

When using negation, you would have to list all the characters you want to exclude - and I'm sure there's more than word boundary and question mark you want to exclude.

Comment: True, but I'm looking for an answer that uses negative character class, or else explains why using a negative character class like on regular-expressions.info wouldn't work.

Comment: The problem with negation though is that you would have to list all the characters you want to exclude - and I'm sure there's more than word boundary and question mark you want to exclude.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand negation then. Doesn't the regex engine stop matching and return a match when it hits a negated character?

Comment: Ah, so it just skips the word-ending character and continues matching?

Comment: Yes. Negation means: any character not in the list matches. Then it just moves on to matching the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Since word boundaries are usually defined by white space why not use

```
\<w[^[:space:]]+\>
```

If you want to include a simple `w` you may also use

```
\<w[^[:space:]]*\>
```

Comment: Yes, this also works. Part of understanding this was that negated class just means match something that's not part of the negated set, plus knowing that end of word is sometimes better defined by whitespace.